# Delete core data object instance - must relations really be set to nil?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, core-data

Deleting a core data object on iOS is a really common task, I'd say. But it has a common problem that I just can't figure out myself: if the instance has relations set, the deletion fails with `NSValidationRelationshipDeniedDeleteError` (1600). This is the case even if all relations, including inverse, are set to "optional". [Apple's documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/Reference/reference.html) this error code denotes that "some relationship with delete rule NSDeleteRuleDeny is non-empty". This is not the case here; all relationships have a delete rule of "nullify".

I even tried with the simplest relation I could think of, using the employee and department example of Apple's documentation. I can delete an employee as long as it has no department set.

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463382/core-data-relationships-cause-save-error-after-delete) about this problem; the solution there is to set all relations to nil before saving the MOC. This indeed works, but it does not make the faintest sense to me.

My question: is this really common practice? How does this make sense? What does everybody else do to delete Core Data objects with relations?

PS: In case anybody is interested, this is my code to clear the relations; `entityInstance` is the instance to be deleted. The code is generic for my app, meaning it clears all relations of the entity to be deleted:

```
NSEntityDescription *ed = entityInstance.entity;
NSDictionary *relations = [ed relationshipsByName];
NSArray *keys = [relations allKeys];
[keys enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  [entityInstance setValue:nil forKey:(NSString*) obj];
}];
```

Comment: check again (and after that again) that your deletion rules are nullify. Then remove the app from device/simulator and do a clean built. I've never encountered something like this. I guess you checked for custom relationship setters too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked a hundred times, even let someone else look over it. The model is not complex. All nullify. I also tried removing app and data, clean rebuild, no success. There are no custom setters at all...

Comment: In that case, and given your solution you might want to file a radar with an example project. That would at least help track down the root cause.